# Core Data: Programmatically inherited relations become nil

Tags: ios, inheritance, core-data

I'm using Core Data and create my data model programmatically.
I can't get inheritance to work, because in the children the `destinationEntity` of inherited `NSRelationshipDescription`'s become always nil.

Tests showed me that the problem only occurs if I do the inheritance programmatically, if I do it via the Xcode Model Editor the `destinationEntity` keeps the correct value also in the childs.

Has anyone any idea what went wrong?

Here the playground:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

func listPropertiesFrom(entity: NSEntityDescription) {
    print("========== Properties from entity \"\(entity.name!)\" ============")
    for property in entity.properties {
        print(property)
    }
}

class Rect: NSManagedObject {
}

class Base: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var rect: Rect
}

class Child: Base {
}

// ----------- Define Rect ----------

let rectEntity = NSEntityDescription()
rectEntity.name = "rect"
rectEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Rect"

// ----------- Define Base -----------

let baseEntity = NSEntityDescription()
baseEntity.name = "base"
baseEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Base"
baseEntity.isAbstract = true

let rectRelation: NSRelationshipDescription = NSRelationshipDescription()
rectRelation.name = "rect"

// >>>>>>>>>>> Error: This becomes nil in the child! >>>>>>>>>>>
rectRelation.destinationEntity = rectEntity

rectRelation.minCount = 1
rectRelation.maxCount = 1
rectRelation.isOptional = false
rectRelation.deleteRule = NSDeleteRule.cascadeDeleteRule

baseEntity.properties = [rectRelation]

// ----------- Define Child ------------

let childEntity = NSEntityDescription()
childEntity.name = "child"
childEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Child"

baseEntity.subentities.append(childEntity)

// No own properties! All inherited!

// -----------

listPropertiesFrom(entity: baseEntity)
listPropertiesFrom(entity: childEntity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be fixed after the entities are added to a model.  Add the lines:

```
let model = NSManagedObjectModel.init();
model.entities = [baseEntity, rectEntity, childEntity]
```

right before you log.

I don't know why this happens but it seems that the `NSManagedObjectModel` does more than just contain pointers to the entities, it also seems to have a role in managing the inheritance.

This also explains why it works if you use the Model Editor - since that creates a single `NSManagedObjectModel` - not an array of entities.

Comment: Big thanks, that was it. Although it wasn't the complete answer in my case: If I add entites to a `NSManagedObjectModel` which was loaded from a .xcdatamodel it doesn't work, what works is creating another `NSManagedObjectModel` just for the generated entities and then merge them for actual use in another `NSManagedObjectModel`. Like this: `managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.init(byMerging: [modelFromFile, modelFromCode])`. And I can even add a relationship attribute to an entity in modelFromFile which points to an entity in modelFromCode before they are merged.

Comment: You can only add relationship attributes to entities in modelFromFile pointing to entities in modelFromCode before they are merged if there is only 1 .xcdatamodel version, if you have multiple versions you have to add the relationships after the merge.